# Can you secure your swf so it checks if it is running on a recognized environment?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

In flash, is it possible to have your application check that the environment it is running on is "recognized". If so, how do you go about doing it? I want to put my swf on my website and prevent people using it on their site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to check the environment URL against trusted ones.
See [this](http://englishblog.flepstudio.org/tutorials/getting-the-page-url-where-my-swf-is-located/) tutorial to get the URL and other environment variables.