# How to Bind SWFs to a Host?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, copy-protection

I'm working on a major Flash project that is going to be the core content of a site.

As most of you well know, almost any site can be entirely copied by copying the cached files and the hierarchy (files and folders structure), and it would run without problems on an Apache server with PHP enabled, if used.

What I would like to know is: **How to bind SWF files to run on a specific host?**

The SWFs will be encrypted, so outsiders won't have access to the methods used to stop the SWF from running on a different host, question is: what method to use?

I think the solution could be hardcoding the host IP inside the SWF, so if the SWF is looking for 123.123.123.123, only a host with that IP would allow the SWF to run further.

The issue is that AS3 alone can't discover the host IP or could it if it's trying to load a resource file? Anyway, that's why I need your help.

*EDIT: Ok, seems someone asked for something similar earlier: [Can you secure your swf so it checks if it is running on a recognized environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844400/can-you-secure-your-swf-so-it-checks-if-it-is-running-on-a-recognized-environmen)
I'll try that and see how it works, but the question is still open in case anyone has different suggestions.*

Comment: `almost any site can be entirely copied by copying the cached files and the hierarchy (files and folders structure)` - not really true. You will not get any of the server side code that generates the content, only the cached content that was generated. Therefore, having `an Apache server with PHP enabled` is irrelevant, because you would not get any PHP code, just HTML/css/js/etc. All you need to perform that fairly useless task is any web server.

Comment: Yes, you're right. PHP as a cached resource that can be copied isn't a good example, but accessed CSS, JS and XML files needed to properly display the website are all cached and can be easily copied to reproduce a site on any host, and I know I can't prevent that, so I'm looking for a way to make the SWF protect itself, unless there's a different available method which can't be bypassed by just copying cached resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this method to determine if I am on dev or production in my config files.

```
var lc:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
switch ( lc.domain ){
  case "myDomain.com":
  case "":// local file reference  for dev
  case "localhost":// local file reference  for dev
  case "dev.mydomain.com":// local file reference for dev
    break;
  default:
    // unknown domain do crash the app here
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I tested this and it says localhost on my system, but gives the name of the subdomain when testing the site on the subdomain reserved for developing, all without requiring to call external interfaces. Thank you!

Comment: Clean, simple solution. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

One method you could try is a php script that the swf sends a request to and must receive a correct reply from before it continues to operate. Since people can't get at your server-side php, they can't get the needed code to simulate that reply.

Comment: How exactly would I do that? Would I have to create a separate PHP file containing the method that would return the expected response when called by the SWF? Could you provide an example or some sample code so I can get a better idea? Thank you! (+1)

Comment: I'd love to, but I've never done something like that. I'm actually looking to do something similar in a current project, but I only just started the project a couple hours ago and haven't gotten to that part yet. Anyone here sent/received data between a PHP script and AS3 before?

Answer (score 0):

> The SWFs will be encrypted, so outsiders won't have access to the methods used to stop the SWF from running on a different host
>   Since the file will run on a client computer (and thus they key would have to be stored in an accessible way), this isn't really that much of a protection.

The best way would probably be to have part of the SWF-logic on the server, and not give access to that part from third party hosts (by using the crossdomain file).

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of slow- not sure I fully understand how this works. Currently, my SWF cascading is designed like this: small SWF file gets loaded first and displayed on the index page, then that SWF loads another SWF (which is the main preloader), then that SWF loads multiple other SWF files. How would any of these SWFs request resources without them being cached by a client browser by using the crossdomain.xml file?

Comment: That's not quite what I meant - if this was a game for example, it could perform part of the game logic on the server, and deny access to that service with the crossdomain file.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the idea of wrapping main inside a type of preloader, and putting main into a secure dir on the server. I cant remember how this gets around the cache problem, but it had to do with how the wrapper loads main.

Something like this:

```
// preloader.as (embedded in fla)
var imageLoader:Loader;

function randomNumber(low:Number=NaN, high:Number=NaN):Number
{
  var low:Number = low;
  var high:Number = high;

  if(isNaN(low))
  {
    throw new Error("low must be defined");
  }
  if(isNaN(high))
  {
    throw new Error("high must be defined");
  }

  return Math.round(Math.random() * (high - low)) + low;
}
function loadImage(url:String):void {
imageArea.visible=false;
preloader.visible = true;
// Set properties on my Loader object
imageLoader = new Loader();
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, imageLoading);
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
imageArea.addChild(imageLoader);
}
// DOIT!
loadImage("main.sw?"+randomNumber(1000,10000)); //NOT A TYPO!
//loadImage("main.swf"+randomNumber(1000,10000);


function imageLoaded(e:Event):void {
// Hide Preloader
preloader.visible = false;
}

function imageLoading(e:ProgressEvent):void {
// Get current download progress
var loaded:Number = e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal;
// Send progress info to "preloader" movie clip
preloader.SetProgress(loaded);
}

/// this is main.sw  //NOT A TYPO
<?php
// Tried this - abandoned
// session_start();
//
// if(isset($_SESSION["flash"])) {
//   $referrer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
//   $referrer = parse_url($referrer);
//   if($referrer["host"] != $_SESSION["flash"]) {
//     echo "Permission denied.";
//     exit();
//   }
// } else {
//   echo "Permission denied.";
//   exit();
// }
//
// unset($_SESSION["flash"]);

header("Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash");
readfile("/secure/main.swf");
?>

// main.as
public function onCreationComplete(event:Event):void{
  Security.allowDomain( "*" );
  Security.loadPolicyFile( "crossdomain.xml" );
}

// crossdomain.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
   <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
   <cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" />
   </cross-domain-policy>
```

That should get you started. The idea here was to prevent anyone from getting main on their machine- I am not sure if it worked.

Comment: That would just force the client to get a file from the server and not from the cache, but the file would still get cached.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I figured. This was a first attempt made long ago and my post of it was to make a roadmap of some of the entry points where OP could tackle the problem. So I am playing the "its old code and I forget" card here =)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a server-side page generate a key using a date-based algorithm which is passed via flash var to your swf. This way a "copied" key won't work because by that time, the valid date will have passed. From what I understand, this would essentially be like using an RSA token.

Aside from this, any security you have will also need code to be inside your SWF to validate your token. The problem here is that SWFs are known to decompile quite easily. Meaning that your code isn't safe :(  You could obfuscate your AS3 in hopes to confuse any "hackers".

All in all, I've never attempted anything like this, so let us know how it goes!

Comment: Yeah, SWFs can be easily decompiled, but there is commercial software for encrypting SWFs which do a pretty good job at obfuscating contained code (I don't care about protecting media resources, those can never be protected). There may be ways of intercepting whatever the FlashPlayer is getting, but that's beyond the knowledge of your average decompiler user. Regarding the method you described- it could be a solution if the client can't get to the algorithm, but I'm not sure about that. Either way, I find The_asMan's answer to be the most efficient (clean and easy) way to bind a SWF to a host.